# how to compress the size of the picture in django-summernote

Tags: python, django, summernote

The task of tako with how can you compress the image uploaded through django-summernote
For example, I have a picture with a size of 5mb after downloading it should have a size somewhere 500kb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the paths as you wish and choose one of the two when finished:

```
from PIL import Image
foo = Image.open("path to image")
foo = foo.resize((720, 405), Image.ANTIALIAS)
foo.save("path to first new image", quality=95)
foo.save("path to second new image", optimize=True, quality=95)
```